# \newcommand defined for declarative formatting works for \it but not \textit or \emph

Tags: macros, formatting

I defined this `\newcommand` for binomial genus/species names, which should be in italics:

```
\newcommand{\taxon}[1]{{\it #1}}
```

For whatever reason, it only renders the relevant text in italics if I use `\it`; `\emph` or `\textit` do not work (the text is unchanged).

Is there a reason for this strange behaviour? `\textit` and `\emph` work perfectly well if I apply them directly.

Comment: Note that `\textit` takes an argument. Have you written `\textit{#1}`?

Comment: I'm curious: `\it` is deprecated since 1993 (release of LaTeX2e). Which documentation told you to use it?

Answer (score 13):

**Update:** `\it` is deprecated in LaTeX2e, therefore using `\itshape` instead.

`\itshape` is the declarative form. At this time the text is in italics until the current group ends. `\textit` sets the argument in italics:

```
{\itshape ...}
\textit{...}
```

`\emph` emphasizes the argument, whereas `\em` is the declarative form.

The macro definitions for these variants:

```
\newcommand*{\taxon}[1]{{\itshape #1}}
\newcommand*{\taxon}[1]{{\em #1}}
\newcommand*{\taxon}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\newcommand*{\taxon}[1]{\emph{#1}}
```